# Js onload and document.getElementById not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Something in my code is not working. I am new to this. I think it is the onload maybe?

I am trying to convert a 24 clock to a 12 hour GMT server time clock and I have got as far as passing my new code to the CSS div I made.

All the CSS is fine and my coding works well with alert but not with onload and document.getElementById.

```
 <script> 

    var currenttime = '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s a", time())?>' 


    var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)
    var formatTime = (function () {
        function addZero(num) {
            return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
        }

        return function (dt) {
            var formatted = '';

            if (dt) {
                var hours24 = serverdate.getHours();
                var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 2;
                formatted = [formatted, [addZero(hours), addZero(serverdate.getMinutes())].join(":"), hours24 > 11 ? "pm" : "am"].join(" ");            

            }

       document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML=formatted
return formatted;
       }
    })();


    window.onload=function(){
    formatTime(new Date())
    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1><p><span id="servertime"></span></p></h1>

    </body>
```

Comment: `return formatted;` should be last statement in your function

Comment: Thanks although that wasnt the main issue it seems.

Comment: I got it working by moving the onload to a new script section below the Div.

Comment: The function definition for `formatTime` is enclosed in parentheses, so it gets executed when the browser parses it, *not* when it is called through `formatTime()`. And when it's called, `#servertime` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Reeno - No, the indentation is just wrong. It self-executes a function that returns another function that finds the element when called. It's really unnecessarily confusing...

Comment: It works as you have it. http://jsfiddle.net/9hc4t6et/ except its printing "NaN".  If you move the code to a script below the dom elements, then you no longer need the `document.onload` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write this, no need for javascript at all.

```
<h1><p><span id="servertime"><? print date("F d, Y h:i:s a", time())?></span></p></h1>
```

In case you are preparing a periodic update with your javascript (here it makes sense), I suggest using a simple jquery script for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function update() {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'servertime.php',
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(data) {
          $("#servertime").html(data); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
       },
      });
     }
     update();
});
```